# UITableViewScrollPosition with UITableView not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView which should scroll to some index every time its shown. I used the following line in viewWillAppear:

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: currentIndex, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
```

Though this does scroll to the correct cell, it doesn't align the top of that cell with the bottom of the navigation bar. The position of the top of the cell is not even the same every time. How do I fix this?

PS: I use `'UITableViewAutomaticDimension'`for`heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: check if the currentIndex is the right one

Comment: Check if the tableview reloaded data